# Binding data in Angular js in string added via $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs, binding

I am implementing a web interface for a legacy system, so data from server is fixed.  This server data specifies various controls to be shown to the user, e.g. combo-boxes, buttons etc. I have parsed the server data and added the HTML for the controls via $sce.trustAsHtml().

The problem is that the controls are not bound to the model.  And if I put in an ng-change event handler, it is not called with user edits.

I read this helpful post: [call function inside $sce.trustAsHtml() string in Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297638/call-function-inside-sce-trustashtml-string-in-angular-js) that indicates:

> ng-bind-html will simply insert plain old html and 
>   not bother compiling it (so any directives in the 
>   html will not be processed by angular.

So this seems to be my problem. But I don't understand Angular well enough to understand the solution offered by the above post.

I am displaying the dynamic text in the following HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="i in range(0, item.Data.DisplayText.JSArray.length-1)">
  <span ng-bind-html="item.Data.DisplayText.JSArray[i] | trusted_html"></span>
  <span ng-show="!$last"><br></span>
</span>
```

Here is the definition for range():

```
$scope.range = function(min, max){
  var input = [];
  for (var i=min; i<=max; i++) input.push(i);
  return input;
};
```

And here is the definition for the filter:

```
app.filter('trusted_html', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

I have had help setting parts of this up, and have gleaned solutions from here on stack-overflow.  I apologize that can't give links to these original solutions.

What I think I need to do is to extend my trusted_html filter such that it $compiles the text.  But I don't know if that would compile the entire DOM (potentially slow) or just the text parameter.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

ADDENDUM:

I appreciate @Simeon Cheeseman's response.  He indicated that a directive would be better than a filter, as I initially wanted.  I have been studying the documentation and reading posts, and it seems he is 100% correct.  DOM manipulation should occur in directives.  However, I don't like the idea of having one directive (e.g. 'compile-template' from the example in the link above) fix the short-comings of another directive (ng-bind-html).  It seems poor form to me.  How do I know that the ng-bind-html directive will be executed before the compile-template directive is?  And what happens if the execution order is reversed?

So I am going to consider if they could be combined into one function.  I will think out loud here below.  If anyone sees a problem, please let me know.

First, I looked at the ng-bind-html directive from angular.js found here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js  and in this file, I searched for 'ngBindHTML'.

```
var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', '$parse', function($sce, $parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtml);

    var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
    function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

    scope.$watch(getStringValue, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction(value) {
      element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
    });
 };
```

}];

The above is not in the form of app.directive(), and it doesn't return a {link: fun()} object.  So I am not exactly sure if this directly applicable to compare to the compile-template directive below.   However, I did find, on line 2025, the following.  So I think I am on the right path:

```
ngBindHtml: ngBindHtmlDirective,
```

So this ngBindHtmlDirective is somehow acting as ngBindHtml.

I am going to pick apart the code above, and reform it.  And FYI, I am relatively new to javascript, and anonymous functions and closures are still a bit new to me.  So I am trying to remove anonymous functions for my clarity.  I'll add some comments from info I have picked up on Angular's website etc.

```
var DirectiveFnFactory = function($sce, $parse) {

  var DirectiveHandlerFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
    //Input:  scope = an Angular scope object 
    //        element = the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches
    //        attr = a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute 
    //               names and their corresponding attribute values
    //closure scope input: $compile object
    //                     $parse object
    //Result: none

    element.addClass('ng-binding');
    // .addClass is jQuery:  http://api.jquery.com/addclass/
    //  adds class to element
    element.data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtml);
    //  adds value to key of '$binding';

    var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml); 
    //Input:  attr.ngBindHtml should be the HTML to be bound.
    //Result:  $parse() returns a function which represents the 
    //         compiled input expression.
    //  This function will have this signature: 
    //     function(context, locals)    
    //            context – {object} – an object against which any expressions 
    //                                 embedded in the strings are evaluated against 
    //                                 (typically a scope object).
    //            locals – {object=} – local variables context object, useful for 
    //                                 overriding values in context.
    //     The returned function also has the following properties:
    //       literal – {boolean} – whether the expression's top-level node is a 
    //                             JavaScript literal.
    //                           constant – {boolean} – whether the expression is made 
    //                             entirely of JavaScript constant literals.
    //        assign – {?function(context, value)} – if the expression is assignable, 
    //                             this will be set to a function to change its value 
    //                             on the given context.

    function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }
    //First, this is executing the function that was returned by parsed(), 
    //    passing scope that was given to DirectiveHandlerFn()
    //Next converting Fn() output to string. 
    //In the case of binding HTML. I would think that the output of this would be HTML

    var watchListener = function ngBindHtmlWatchAction(value) {
      element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
      //.html is jquery: http://api.jquery.com/html/
      //  Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements
      //    or set the HTML contents of every matched element.
    }

    scope.$watch(getStringValue, watchListener);
    //$watch signature: 
    //  $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
    //  This registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the 
    //    watchExpression()  changes
    //  The listener() has this signature (determined by example, not API documents!):
    //     listener(newValue, oldValue);
    //  The listener is called automagically by Angular when the value changes.
  }

  return DirectiveHandlerFn;
}

var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', '$parse', DirectiveFnFactory];
```

OK, now I will first quote the compileTemplate directive, (from here: [call function inside $sce.trustAsHtml() string in Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297638/call-function-inside-sce-trustashtml-string-in-angular-js)):

```
.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attar){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

            //Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  
               //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we 
               //do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }         
    }
});
```

And now pick it apart to allow commenting:

```
var DirectiveObjFactory = function($compile, $parse){
    //input: $compile object
    //       $parse object

    var DirectiveHandlerFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
        //Input:  scope = an Angular scope object 
        //        element = the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches
        //        attr = a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute 
        //               names and their corresponding attribute values
        //closure scope vars: $compile object
        //                    $parse object
        //Result: none

        var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
        //Input:  attr.ngBindHtml should be the HTML to be bound.
        //Result:  $parse() returns a function which represents the 
        //         compiled input expression.
        //  This resulted function will have this signature: 
        //     function(context, locals)    
        //            context – {object} – an object against which any expressions 
        //                             embedded in the strings are evaluated against 
        //                             (typically a scope object).
        //            locals – {object=} – local variables context object, useful for 
        //                             overriding values in context.
        //     The returned function also has the following properties:
        //       literal – {boolean} – whether the expression's top-level node is a 
        //                         JavaScript literal.
        //       constant – {boolean} – whether the expression is made 
        //                             entirely of JavaScript constant literals.
        //        assign – {?function(context, value)} – if the expr is assignable, 
        //                          this will be set to a function to change its value 
        //                             on the given context.

       function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }
        //First, this is executing the function that was returned by parsed(), 
        //    passing scope that was given to DirectiveHandlerFn()
        //Next converting Fn() output to string. 
        //In the case of binding HTML. I would think that the output of this 
        //  would be HTML

        var watchListener = function ngBindHtmlWatchAction(value) {
          //Input: value -- actual the newValue. (oldValue not accepted here)
          //Locally scoped vars used -- element, scope

          // -- Adding Below is from ngbindHtml ------------
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
          //.html is jquery: http://api.jquery.com/html/
          //Gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched 
          //    elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.
          // -- End addition  ------------

          var compFn = $compile(element, null, -9999);
          //NOTE: I can't find formal documentation for the parameters for $compile()
          //      below is from examples found...
          //Input: element -- the HTML element to compile
          //       transcludeFunction -- null here.
          //       maxPriority -- "The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we 
          //                       do not recompile ourselves"
          //$compile() compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and 
          //    produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope 
          //    and the template together.
          //  The returned function accepts a scope variable, against which the code
          //    is evaluated. 
          compFn(scope); // execute the returned function, passing scope  
        } // end watchListener

        scope.$watch(getStringValue, watchListener);
        //$watch() function signature: 
        //  $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
        //  This registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the 
        //    watchExpression changes
        //  The supplied listener() should have this signature:
        //     listener(newValue, oldValue);
        //  The listener is called automagically by Angular when the value changes.

    } // end DirectiveHandlerFn

    return {link: DirectiveHandlerFn}         

} // end DirectiveObjFactory

app.directive('compileTemplate', DirectiveObjFactory);
```

I think I am almost there.  Let me try to bring this all back together...

```
.directive('bindAndWatchHtml', ['$sce', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

            //Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  
                //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }         
    }
}]);
```

Hopefully this will bind AND compile the html, and trust the HTML at the same time.

Now for testing...

ADDENDUM:

Doesn't work..  On the line:

```
element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
```

it complains the $sce is not defined.

...

I changed the following line, and that allows $sce to be defined.

```
app.directive('bindAndWatchTrustedHtml0', ['$compile', '$parse', '$sce',
                                       function($compile, $parse, $sce){ ...
```

Next I get an error about trying to use a secure text in an insecure location....

....

This is just taking too long.  I'm giving up on this.  I used this, as per the original link at the very top, and it works.

```
<span ng-bind-html="item.Data.DisplayText.JSArray[i] | trusted_html" compile-template>
</span>
```

Comment: what error you are getting in console?

Comment: @pankajparkar -- no error in the console.  Just when I edit the data, the hg-change event handler doesn't fire, and the edits are not stored in the model.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/service/$compile for how to compile.

Basically you'd call `compiledHtml = $compile('<div>' + text + '</div>')($scope).html()`.

I think you're going to be better off creating a directive than using a filter though as you'll need the `$scope` variable to compile.

Maybe you could make use of [ngBindTemplate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) or [ngInclude](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)