# how to execute js functions in inline js which is added through ng-bind-html of angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularjs,so I am assuming there is something simple which I am missing about this. I am facing an issue where my back-end sends some html which includes a script tag which has some js example is as under.

```
<!--some html-->
<script>
//some js code
caption_class_fn = function(){
  $('.jwcaptions').addClass('%s')//%s as its added from backend
}
caption_class_fn()
</script>
```

This html is then filled into `$scope.htmlval` which is bound with an html element like this `ng-bind-html="htmlval".` The issue I am facing is that I want to execute a js function which is present in side the script tags. I tried alert, console.log but nothing seems to work. Although once the page is loaded if I try the same fucntion from console it works.Any idea how can i achieve this with minimum code change. I also tried to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297638/call-function-inside-sce-trustashtml-string-in-angular-js) but this also isn't working for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm also new to angularjs and I not sure where to search for the solution or what to start with. It might be it just do not work that way.