# ng-bind-html does not display form component like textbox,button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

```
 $scope.data="<h2>here we have text boxes and button</h2><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>inside Basic</button>"+"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>inside Primary</button>"+" Name inside<input type='text' name='namein' /><br>Age indise :: <input type='text' name='agein' /><br></form>"; 

<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

This is the content I have used in ng-bind-html, but, it doesn't  display text box and button.I have tried same code in plunker but it did not work there.

Comment: Please edit your question with `$scope.data`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) because a button (like many others elements) is not a trusted element angular can bind without that:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/mnsp088t/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">a new button!</button>');
}]);
```

If you need to use Angular function inside the ng-bind-html so you need a directive like this ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298466/286304)):

```
.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

            //Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }         
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="data" compile-template></div>
```

With `$compile` you can tell to compile the string to be used as HTML written directly in the view.

Comment: But when we add ng-click="showName()" on the button then its not working.Will you please help me around this issue.

Comment: Because that's not the way to do it. Use ng-if if you need to add/remove portion of html

Comment: But if the html code is provided by back end api then how can we use ng-if in this case.

Comment: Edited answer with the directive you should use.

Comment: Its working fine but one more question If we want to access content of text box inside ng-bind-html outside ng-bind-html on click of any button then how will we do it??

Comment: Sorry can't understand, please write another question or edit yours with relative code. Then if this answer solved your initial problem you should accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86955/discussion-between-keshav-and-michelem).