# AngulaJs ng-click in expression html

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying HTML in a AngularJS expression.

In My HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>
```

And In My Controller

```
$scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div class='my-style' ng-click='onClick(10)'>click me</div>");

$scope.onClick = function(value)
{
    console.log("onClick: value:"+value);
}
```

But I am not able to get the click event

**UPDATE**

In one of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179) I see it has be described about how to add HTML tags in the text or how to compile HTML. But my question is related to how to get ng-click event from the complied HTML. I don't see any of the answers providing this solution.

Comment: Find for you, go through with this. You have to make directive for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297638/call-function-inside-sce-trustashtml-string-in-angular-js/20298466#20298466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for again writing the code : 
 First give a unique id to your div :

```
        <div id="test"></div>
```

Then Change that code to below one:

```
   var myText = "<div class='my-style' ng-click='onClick(10)'>click me</div>";

    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#test'));
    var generated = element.html(myText);
    $compile(generated.contents())($scope);
```

This will manage your code to work. cheers!

Comment: @SURAJEET SINGH Bisht: I am not facing problem with HTML display, I am able to see HTML but I am facing issue related to ng-click I am not able  get the click event with inserted HTML code.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. does it have any other implication on the angular app any side effects ?

Comment: no never.dont wry about it. it only render the current event

Comment: Will it possible to provide explanation for code:     var generated = element.html(myText);
    $compile(generated.contents())($scope);     What this code does exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Use directive to implement this functionality. Check demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/tTgVCMt7JqvaQOrjhLLL?p=preview

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.testClick = function(value) {
      alert("onClick: value:"+value);
  };
});

app.directive("clickDynamic", function(){
   return {
       template:"<div class='my-style' ng-click='testClick(10)'>click me</div>"
   };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div click-dynamic></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The HTML text that I am generating is dynamic and it is generated at the runtime (depending on cloud API call response). I need to build this HTML text from controller. and also there are multiple divs which will have this dynamic text.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have append the html using id or class                 
var add = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#updatechoose' ) );
                 add.append('<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="updatedata in getdata">'+
                                '<div>'+  
                                '<input type="file" id="imgupload" ng-model="attachment" imgepath="{{updatedata.imagepath}}" imgname="{{updatedata.imagename}}" name="file[]"  style="padding-left: 15px;" class="imgupload col-md-4 cropit-image-input" />'+
                                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" **ng-click="remove()"**></i>'+
                                '</div>'+   
                            '</div>');
```

Comment: I tested this way but not able to get the click event in my controller. Can you post working example?

Comment: The above example working fine in my project .In html code <div id="updatechoose" style="margin-left: 35%;" class="remove"></div>

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use **plain javascript** and get the **scope**. This way you can call your inside methods.

```
<div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>
$scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml( '<div class="button" onClick="var scope = angular.element(this).scope();scope.testClick(10);">click me</div>' );
```

Please note that I'm using **onClick** instead of ng-click, then I get the scope, this way I can call the inner methods.
It's a dirty solution, but maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a snippet, which shows an implementation via a directive and the $compile service.

```js
angular.module('TestApp', [])
  .directive('compileDir', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        dynTpl: '='
      },
      template: 'Num clicked: {{numClicked}}',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        scope.numClicked = 0;
        scope.click = function() {
          scope.numClicked++;
        };

        var tpl = $compile(scope.dynTpl)(scope);
        elem.append(tpl);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <compile-dir dyn-tpl="'<button ng-click=\'click()\'>Click</button>'"></compile-dir>
</div>
```